# Node.js pass Basic Authorization to odata service

Tags: node.js, express, odata

I have a backend using Node.js with Express and it is reaching out to an Odata service to retrieve some data.

To do so it is using `"odata": "^1.3.1"` : https://www.npmjs.com/package/odata/v/1.3.1

However, the service requires I pass Basic Authentication in the request.

I do not see anywhere in their documentation on how to do so. Below is my call to the service within a route, how can I add Basic Authentication to the request?

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const o = require('odata').o;

process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0;

router.get('/otasks', function(req, res) {
    o(process.env.ODATA_SERVER)
        .get()
        .query()
        .then(data => res.json({ payload: data }))
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            return res.json({ payload: "error" });
        });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basic access authentication: When the user agent wants to send authentication credentials to the
> server, it may use the Authorization header field.
> [Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)

According to the package [document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/odata#options), you can provide headers to your request. Then your logic code will become like this:

```
...
o(process.env.ODATA_SERVER, {
    headers: { 'Authorization': `Basic ${Buffer.from('username:password').toString('base64')}` },
})
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up just using Axios but nice to know it supports the same syntax.